# Class mapping from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration

I am working on migrating an extension from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.

I want to know about the class migration followed between Magento 1.x to Magento 2.

Can anyone please help me in tracing the class-mapping followed in Magento 2 from Magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, there is no exact place to find list the ( in web )

But you can identify the Classes declaration and naming convention like

**Core Classes**

```
vendor\magento\framework\
```

For example, Varien_Object in Magento 1 is equivalent to \Magento\Framework\DataObject

**Modules**

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog   (vendor name/module name - Magento_Catalog)
```

Also in the Magento 2, there are a set of [classes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36038/what-type-of-classes-are-generated-in-magento-2) that are generated automatically and stored in `var/generation`

**Lib**

```
root\lib
```

**Frameworks**

```
vendor/zendframework
vendor/ symfony
```

To find the exact class , you can go by naming convention in Magento 2 or use `grep -i -n -r "string" /var/related folder ( Ubuntu )` for exact search.

Hope this helps.